# in UniswapV2Pair contract I don't understand Maths behind price0Cummulative and price1Cummulative?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, uniswap, uniswapv3

I know TWAP formula = priceDifference / timeElapsed;

but still not able to get how uniswapv2 is doing that.

https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L79

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the math contracts:  https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/libraries/UQ112x112.sol

And I know this is for v3, but this article explains the twaps in Uniswap a bit more (note it has more to do with ticks than actual time):  https://chaoslabs.xyz/posts/chaos-labs-uniswap-v3-twap-deep-dive-pt-1.